# Получить дни недели и даты следующих 10 дней

Tags: android, java, calendar

Добрый день.

Хотел бы узнать, как можно получить из календаря названия дней недели и числа в формате "DD-MM-YYYY".

Заранее всем большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy (EEEE)");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Log.d("tag", formatter.format(c.getTime()));
}
```